# About absolute convergent series in Banach space and its bounded linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, absolute-convergence

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in Banach space $X$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(x_n)|< \infty$  for all bounded linear functional $f \in X'$.

Show that there exists $M\geq 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(x_n)| \leq M \|f\|$, for all $f\in X'$.

What I have tried:

Since $|f(x_n)| \leq \|f\| \| x_n\|$, if we can obtain $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\| \leq M$, the proof can be got. But I don't know in what condition a sequence in Banach space will be absolute convergent.

And from the condition we can know that $f(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n) < \infty$.

Comment: To complement the answer: The assumption of your question is actually always fulfilled when the sequence is unconditionally convergent (I don't know if the converse holds aswell). This however is weaker than absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $T_n:X'\to l^1(\mathbb C)$ by
$$T_n(f)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),...,f(x_n),0,0,0...),\;f\in X'.$$
For each $f$ the sequence $\{\|T_n(f)\|_{l^1}\}_n$ is bounded. Now apply Uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So $\|T_n\| = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\|x_i\|$ is bounded for all $n\geq 1$ according to the Uniform boundedness principle which concludes the proof.